# How to use an implementation to produce output

Tags: java, interface

I am reading [this Oracle Java interface tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

If you don't want to grapple with the specific coding error I made, I am looking for a little more information than the tutorial provides: how do I get the interface example to actually use the methods defined in the ACMEBicycle section, such as the print method? I cannot seem to copy paste past examples nor modify them in a way that is accepted by the compiler. (Or perhaps more properly, the thing that runs the code?)

The code there does not seem to be complete, seemingly relying upon the reader to conduct experiments to find the proper syntax. I had no success. First I tried to change the code in "Good Coding practice with respect to interface versus class versus super class" to use an interface to define percolation and its 3 sites. I realized this gave me too many uncontrolled variables because it was my own code, so I decided to use the bicycle example provided instead. In order to actually use what I've set up, I tried something analogous to [the bicycledemo example under the class tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html). Here is that code:

```
package javaapplication5;

/** * * @author Jeff */ 
 interface Bicycle {

//  wheel revolutions per minute
void changeCadence(int newValue);

void changeGear(int newValue);

void speedUp(int increment);

void applyBrakes(int decrement);
}

class ACMEBicycle implements Bicycle {

int cadence = 0;
int speed = 0;
int gear = 1;
// The compiler will now require that methods
// changeCadence, changeGear, speedUp, and applyBrakes 
// all be implemented. Compilation will fail if those    
// methods are missing from this class.

void changeCadence(int newValue) {
     cadence = newValue;
}

void changeGear(int newValue) {
     gear = newValue;
}

void speedUp(int increment) {
     speed = speed + increment;   
}

void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
     speed = speed - decrement;
}

void printStates() {
     System.out.println("cadence:" +
         cadence + " speed:" + 
         speed + " gear:" + gear);
}
}

class ACMEBycicle{ ACMEBycicle.printStates() }

public class JavaApplication5 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

The current version shows me just trying to use a simple **print** command that I had already defined as part of the specific implementation **ACMEBicycle** of the `interface Bicycle`. I tried also copying the **bicycledemo** example in instead of writing my own code, except I felt the need to replace **Bicycle** with **ACMEBicycle** That results in

```
    package javaapplication5;

    /** * * @author Jeff */ 

    interface Bicycle {

    //wheel revolutions per minute
    void changeCadence(int newValue);

    void changeGear(int newValue);

    void speedUp(int increment);

    void applyBrakes(int decrement);
    }

    class ACMEBicycle implements Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    // The compiler will now require that methods 
    // changeCadence, changeGear, speedUp, and applyBrakes 
    // all be implemented. Compilation will fail if those 
    // methods are missing from this class.

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
      }
    }

    class BicycleDemo { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        ACMEBicycle bike1 = new ACMEBicycle();
        ACMEBicycle bike2 = new ACMEBicycle();


        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
    }

    public class JavaApplication5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       }
    }
```

Comment: Is there an extra { at the end of your BicycleDemo class

Comment: I think it was right, but poorly formatted.  My apologies.  One of the "}" was for closing void main.

Comment: Interestingly, if you write `Bicycle bike = new ACMEBicycle();` youll encounter the fact that the printstates method doesnt exist because the static type of bike is Bicycle, which has no such method. You can access the method via a cast or by adding to the interface. A tricky and fun issue.

Comment: Obligatory links of pages to read before you post on SO: rewrite the code into good [sample code](http://sscce.org/) and make the [question as perfect](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) as possible. In particular, a question should state what you expect and what you actually get, which includes any error messages (this question is currently missing the exact errors). Also, there's a good chance whatever error(s) you're experiencing already have a Q&A; with the exact error message, you can probably find them.

Comment: ... See also [Getting Answers](https://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have already closed the class once after bike2.printStates();
Remove the second }

Comment: The code was poorly formatted, my apologies.  One of the "}" is for closing the void main.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with each sample. One is addressed on the tutorial page you reference:

> Note: To actually compile the ACMEBicycle class, you'll need to add the public keyword to the beginning of the implemented interface methods.